# How does 'muting' work for Gmail?

Tags: gmail, mute

My understanding was that when you "muted" a conversation in Gmail, future emails came in but they didn't bring that conversation back into the inbox.  I clearly don't understand how this feature works because I just muted a conversation, and archived it, and a new email came in and it shows as unread again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct.  Muting a conversation archives it and any new emails that fall under the conversation (same subject) will skip the inbox and be archived.

I'm guessing you might be stuck on this next part though, as it seems to lessen the value of the feature itself.

Muting a conversation does not **normally** work if your email is in the `To` or `Cc` field. **However, there is now a feature in Gmail Labs called Smart Mute that will keep a thread archived as long as your email address was not *added* to the `To` or `Cc` after you clicked `Mute`.**

Comment: Yes, thats the issue. blerg. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @MichaelPryor, agreed.  To me, it seems like that is the entire reason for the feature!

Answer (score 3):

To expand on @Rebecca's excellent answer: This feature began life inside Google as a way to mute conversations on the panoply of internal mailing lists.  If you were subscribed to `misc@google.com`, you saw every reply to every thread, but those replies were to `misc@google.com`, not to you. The designers didn't allow for the fact that most people outside Google will want to mute conversations that are actually CC'ed to them.