# Am I using the Gmail 'mute' properly?

Tags: gmail, mute

I tried to search for some answers, both here and on forums but it's very hard to find a reliable one as Google has changed its functionality couple of times so old answers don't apply anymore.

I'm signed up in several mailing lists on SourceForge. A typical email looks like this:

```
from:        User <user@email.fr> via lists.sourceforge.net 
to:          emutos-devel@lists.sourceforge.net
mailing list:emutos-devel.lists.sourceforge.net
mailed-by:   lists.sourceforge.net
```

I've a simple rule applied there (mark it with a label).

Now, if I press 'Mute', I see the thread marked as muted but it doesn't stop showing new emails in Inbox from this thread (marked as muted, labeled with my label and marked as new/unread)! I don't need to participate in that conversation at all so it's definitely not the case of sending someone something to me directly.

So I don't know, am I doing something wrong here?

Do I have to delete/archive the thread after muting it?

Comment: Seems like you're doing it right to me. See also: [How does 'muting' work for gmail?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/9482)